# Why does extracting an explicit `null` in JSONB as text yield an SQL `null`?

Tags: json, postgresql, null, jsonb

I am trying to understand handling `null`s in PostgreSQL's `jsonb` type.  Because of

```
# select 'null'::jsonb is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

I assume that they are different than SQL `null`s (which makes sense) - [according to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html),

> SQL NULL is a different concept.

Therefore, these two queries are not surprising at all:

```
# select '{"a": 1, "b": null}'::jsonb->'b' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

# select '{"a": 1, "b": null}'::jsonb->'c' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

per [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> The field/element/path extraction operators return NULL, rather than failing, if the JSON input does not have the right structure to match the request; for example if no such element exists.

Where the surprise begins, however, is this:

```
# select '{"a": 1, "b": null}'::jsonb->>'b' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

# select '{"a": 1, "b": null}'::jsonb->>'c' is null;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The latter one I can understand - we get an SQL `null` from the extraction, and casting a `null` to `text` leaves it as `null` - I assume `->>` works that way, as [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) says

> The field/element/path extraction operators return the same type as their left-hand input (either json or jsonb), except for those specified as returning text, which coerce the value to text.

(BTW, I could not find a confirmation that casting an SQL `null` to any other type yields `null` again in PostgreSQL - is it written somewhere explicitly?)

But the former is a mystery to me.  The extraction should get me a `jsonb` `null`, and I thought casting to `text` should give me `'null'` (i.e., a string saying "null"), just like

```
# select ('null'::jsonb)::text;
 text 
------
 null
(1 row)
```

But yet it returns a proper SQL `null`.

Why is that so?

Comment: What else would it return?  It can't return a JSON null, as the operator explicitly does not return JSON at all.  It has to apply **some** mapping, and if not this is one then what?

Comment: Well, I said that - I expected the string `'null'`, like in `select ('null'::jsonb)::text;`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent this is a matter of opinion of the implementor; when converting between JSON data types and SQL data types, it is not always possible to find a perfect correspondence, particularly since SQL NULL is so weird.

But there is a certain logic to how it is implemented.

```
SELECT (JSONB '{"a": "null"}' -> 'a')::text,
       (JSONB '{"a": null}' -> 'a')::text;

  text  | text 
--------+------
 "null" | null
(1 row)
```

Casting to `text` always produces a result that, when cast back to the original type, produces the original value. That is a design principle in PostgreSQL.

So the JSON string `"null"` and the JSON `null` will be cast to different strings.

Now look at this:

```
SELECT JSONB '{"a": "null"}' ->> 'a',
       JSONB '{"a": null}' ->> 'a';

 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 null     | 
(1 row)
```

Here, different to the cast above, PostgreSQL tries to find the closest equivalent of the JSON value in SQL. You wouldn't want the string `"null"` to retain its double quotes, because that would be quite a different string in SQL, right?

But on the other hand it would also not feel right if `"null"` and `null` were represented the same way in SQL, would it?

As far as I know, JSON `null` means “not there”, and that is one of the meanings of SQL NULL. Also, having a JSON attribute with a value of `null` means about the same thing as omitting that attribute, doesn't it?

So while there is room for debate, I think there is some rhyme and reason behind the way it is implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very interesting, and now makes sense to me. `<shameless-plug>` Here is my blog entry about it: http://mbork.pl/2020-02-15_PostgreSQL_and_null_values_in_jsonb `</shameless-plug>`

Comment: I couldn't find a way to comment on your blog, so I put it here: 1. there is an "inn" instead of an "in", 2. Concerning "casting `null` to anything results in `null` (I could not find evidence for this in the PostgreSQL manual, but a few experiments seem to confirm this behavior, and it makes perfect sense)": This is decreed by the SQL standard: "Every data type includes a special value, called the *null* value, sometimes denoted by the keyword `NULL`."

Comment: Thanks! The link to the comment page is at the bottom left, so feel free to leave the comment about `NULL`s (I fixed the typo).